# Word that means lying in bed after waking up, enjoying the peace and tranquility

Tags: single-word-requests

I saw this word and definition about two months ago, but I can't remember where; I've been trying to find it ever since. I searched here and found a "lie-in" and elsewhere, "hurkle-durkle", but they both have more negative connotations.

This is a beautiful word for a wonderful feeling and has a good connotation. It's usually the feeling on a weekend or holiday morning when you can lie in bed and be grateful and happy to enjoy the peace and relaxation. Does anyone know a word for that feeling?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151134/discussion-on-question-by-donna-word-that-means-lying-in-bed-after-waking-up-en); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 12):

*Laze* might work:

> **laze** *verb*
> **1.a.** *intransitive.* To lie, move, or act in a sleepy listless fashion; to enjoy oneself lazily. Also with adverbs.
> <sub>[selected sample]</sub>
>  <sub>**1868**   I had a very
> pleasant time, sailing, fishing, and lazing about.</sub>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Comment: I do like the fact that this includes "to enjoy oneself...", but I wonder if there are still other words that we can come up with, the "one" I recently heard.

Comment: *lazing* - no one ever says *laze*

Comment: I would say "having a laze around"

Comment: @Mazura I wouldn't say "having a laze" but I would say "laze around."

Comment: As immortalized for me by Freddie Mercury in "Lazing on a Sunday Afternoon"! :)

Answer (score 5):

There's "lounge"

> intransitive verb

: to act or move idly or lazily : LOAF
was lounging on the sofa
transitive verb
: to pass (time) 
idly returned to Rome to lounge away the remainder of his days —J. A. Froude

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lounge

Comment: This is another close word but still not the new one. I wonder if I could combine all of these into one word that I didn't know before--that's the word I'm looking for. Please continue to answer if you have a different word.

Answer (score 4):

**Chilling** in bed.

> a cool way of telling someone you sat around doing nothing.

Source: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chilling

Answer (score 3):

*Luxuriate* might work:

> **luxuriate** *verb*
> **2.b.** In immaterial sense: To take great delight, revel *in* (something).
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Comment: This isn't the word I recently learned, but I do like it for this feeling.

Comment: Sorry, but for me this just doesn't fit. One can luxuriate in new/clean sheets, or something like that, but enjoying a lie-in just doesn't match this format.

Answer (score 3):

Also potentially relevant is *Linger*:

> Verb
>
> linger (third-person singular simple present lingers, present participle lingering, simple past and past participle lingered)
>
> 1. (intransitive) To stay or remain in a place or situation, especially as if unwilling to depart or not easily able to do so.
> 2. (intransitive) To remain alive or existent although still proceeding toward death or extinction; to die gradually.
> 3. (intransitive, often followed by on) To consider or contemplate for a period of time; to engage in analytic thinking or discussion.

Source: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/linger#English

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned and discounted **hurkle-durkle**, but I’d like to argue that it’s the correct one anyway. This image has popped up frequently on social media meme posts in the past year or so, and fits both your timeline and the “good connotation”:

> Happiness is **HURKLE-DURKLING**.

[image: a “word of the day” post, with small stars on a gray background, defining the 200-year-old Scottish term, hurkle-durkle: “To lounge in bed long after it’s time to get up.”]

Comment: This does seem familiar, and I wonder if that is where I saw it. When it's stated this way, it does sound much nicer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions from Roget's Thesaurus:

- 278 (Slowness) Languish
- 679 (Inactivity) Slumber, Snooze, Doze
- 683 (Repose) Lounge

Answer (score 1):

Bask:

> Verb
>
> bask (third-person singular simple present basks, present participle basking, simple past and past participle basked)
>
> 1. To bathe in warmth; to be exposed to pleasant heat.
> 2. (figurative) To take great pleasure or satisfaction; to feel warmth or happiness. (Usually followed by "in".)

Source: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bask

Comment: I feel like "bask" is only used when there's some external source of the pleasure -- bask in the glory of victory, bask in his mother's attention, bask in the sun. Even if a lizard basks on a rock, the sun is implied.

Comment: I am enjoying warmth of the covers on my bed, but that's not the main pleasure here.

Comment: In addition to basking in the warmth of the covers, you can bask in the quiet of the morning, knowing that when you get out of bed and start taking creaking steps on the stairs and make all the sounds that preparing breakfast makes, everyone will wake up and the quiet will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

"vegging out" fits well. aka - act like a vegetable.

Google search, [many examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=vegging+out&oq=vegging+out&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyCQgAEEUYORiABDIHCAEQABiABDIHCAIQABiABDIHCAMQABiABDIHCAQQABiABDIHCAUQABiABDIHCAYQABiABDIHCAcQABiABDIHCAgQABiABDIHCAkQABiABKgCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/veg-out)

Bonus:

A whole slew of Cambridge results [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/thesaurus/articles/to-spend-time-doing-nothing-or-very-little) for
"**to spend time doing nothing or very little
to spend time doing nothing or very little.**"

Comment: Very good contemporary answer

Answer (score 0):

I've found *Snerdle*, *Croozle*, *Snoodle*, *Snuzzle*, *Snudge*

But it is beyond my ability to find an official definition for any of them beyond social media posts claiming some variant of being snug, often in the morning. They're all at best archaic and dialectal if not recent-ish fabrications so are unlikely to be understood out of context.

*Snerdle* was "tweeted" by @susie_dent a few months ago, which would fit your timeline.

Comment: Thank you for posted these. I've never heard of any of these but will look into them further. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another rare Scottish word, **grufeling**, which the 1825 Jamieson’s Etymological Dictionary of the [Scottish Language](https://electricscotland.com/history/jamieson/081DictGreToGyt1880.pdf) (pdf page 13)  defined:

> **To be grufeling**: To lie close wrapped up, and in a comfortable-looking manner; used in ridicule.